# How to get all XML nodes by name?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule4

I have input XML like this -

```
<parent>
    <child type="reference">
        <grandChild name="aaa" action="None">
            <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
            <grandChild name="bbb" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
            </grandChild>
            <grandChild name="aaa" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">2</Attribute>
            </grandChild>
        </grandChild>
        <grandChild name="ddd" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
                <grandChild name="aaa" action="None">
                    <Attribute name="xxx">3</Attribute>
                </grandChild>
        </grandChild>
    </child>
</parent>
```

and I want to pull all the grandChild nodes aggregating by their name.For example if I want to pull `payload.parent.child.*grandChild filter($.@name == 'aaa')` I should get array list with 3 grandChild  nodes. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks for the help.

Output -

```
<grandChilds>
    <grandChild name="aaa" action="None">
        <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
    </grandChild>
    <grandChild name="aaa" action="None">
        <Attribute name="xxx">2</Attribute>
    </grandChild>
    <grandChild name="aaa" action="None">
        <Attribute name="xxx">3</Attribute>
    </grandChild>
</grandChilds>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns your required output using ..* selector to retrieve all children and rebuild the output structure:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---

grandChilds:{
    ( payload.parent..*grandChild filter($.@name == 'aaa') map(gc) ->{

    grandChild @(name: gc.@name, action: gc.@action): {
        Attribute @(name: gc.Attribute.@name): gc.Attribute
    }

})

}
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<grandChilds>
  <grandChild name="aaa" action="None">
    <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
  </grandChild>
  <grandChild name="aaa" action="None">
    <Attribute name="xxx">2</Attribute>
  </grandChild>
  <grandChild name="aaa" action="None">
    <Attribute name="xxx">3</Attribute>
  </grandChild>
</grandChilds>
```

[image]